# How can I select multiple ids that contains same word in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to select multiple ids with this code, all of the ids are duplicates like "img1, img2" but nothing works. how can i select all the ids that contains same word without using jQuery or something else.

Here is my code:

```
var resim = document.getElementById("resim");
var originalWidth = resim.style.width; // saves the original width
document.getElementById("resizeButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
  changedivclass();
  if (resim.style.width === "100%") {
    resim.style.width = originalWidth; 
  } else {
    resim.style.width = "100%"; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Would you post your drop-down box code?

Comment: Having numerically sequential IDs is a good indicator that you should give them all the same class (instead of as well as) and use that.

Comment: x.style.width only works with id. i tried almost everything i know

Comment: I'm with Quentin. Can you please share the actual code that didn't work? I suspect you got a collection of some sort, and didn't iterate over it. See ["What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/15261914). When selecting by class, you almost always want a collection of elements, not single one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selectors to do this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=img]')
```

You can find documentation about this selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.php)

Comment: Nice solution. Any idea how this selector (^) is called? I couldn't find documentation about it.

Comment: @fritzcraft you can find documentation here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.php. It is a "starts with" selector

Comment: style.width lines doesn't work when use that unfortunetly

Comment: @BatuhanYurdasan no, of course it doesn't - because you are not dealing with one single element any more, but with a static NodeList. You need to loop over the elements contained in that list, and assign styling to each of them individually.

Comment: MDN has good docs on selectors. Of relevance here: [Substring matching selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors#substring_matching_selectors)